# How to query post with meta?

Tags: post-meta

Hi newbie question just create Rest endpoint for  query-specific post type 
is work fine but did not get data from wp_postmeta
how to query related data or using other WP_ ?

try meta_query but how to add post_id for query relation

```
$all_pms =  new WP_Query( [
 'post_type' => 
     'pms-subscription',
     'post_status'=>'active', 
     'meta_query'=>[
          'pms_subscription_plan_price' => 126 <-- assume it relation but not work
     ]
  ] 
  );
```

thank

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $all_pms =  new WP_Query( [
 'post_type' => 'pms-subscription',
 'post_status'=>'active', 
 'meta_query'=>[
      'meta_key'=>'pms_subscription_plan_price',
      'meta_value'=> '126', // string
      'meta_compare' => '=', // or  > or  < or !=
 ]
] 
);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Although ..re-reading your question I'm not sure what you're exactly looking for..

With this query you're searching posts of type `pms-subscription` having `post_status` =active and custom field with meta_key `pms_subscription_plan_price` and meta_value equals '126'

Comment: Yup can we make meta value dynamic like get post_id from main query